# Get the command from the incoming message in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a discord message; a string like this: `"!ping abrakatabra"`. It's a prefix (`!`), a command (`ping`) and an argument (`abrakatabra`). I want to remove the prefix and everything after the first word to get the command (the string `"ping"`).

How can I do this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is described pretty well in the [discord.js guide](https://v12.discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/commands-with-user-input.html#basic-arguments). Check out the snippet below, I've added some comments to explain how it works:

```js
let content = '!ping abrakatabra pooong'
// prefix is the prefix used before the command
let prefix = '!'

// args is an array of all the words
let args = content
  // .slice() removes the prefix from the message content
  .slice(prefix.length)
  // .trim() removes spaces from both ends
  .trim()
  // .split() creates a new array by dividing the string
  // it splits the string everywhere it finds one or more spaces
  .split(/ +/)

// the shift() method removes the first element and returns it
// it removes "ping" in this case
let command = args.shift().toLowerCase()

console.log({ command })
console.log({ args })
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split the message by the spaces, then `ping` can be extracted with a substring beginning after the first character.

```js
let myMessage = "!ping Fizz";
let command = myMessage.split(" ")[0].substring(1)
console.log(command)
```

Answer (score 0):

[`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) the string with a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

```js
const str = '!ping abrakatabra';
const prefix = '!';

// The regex looks at the start of the string,
// locates the prefix, and then matches everything
// up to the first space in a group.
const regex = new RegExp(`^${prefix}(.+) `);

const match = str.match(regex);

// `match` returns an array. The first element
// will be the whole match, and the other
// elements will be the groups we've identified
console.log(match[1]);
```